# Show relevant div of clicked div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a gallery of images and when you click on an image, a div with boxes is opened. Each image has its own boxes.

So what I am trying to do is when you click on an image the relevant boxes will open.

This is what I have for now -

```
<div class="page-wrap">
 <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="img_slider" class="col-md-12">
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
 <div onclick="showCarousel()">
 <img style="width:100%;" src="img/frida_calo.jpeg" alt="">
 </div>

 <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="img_slider" class="col-md-12">
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
 <div onclick="showCarousel()">
    <img style="width:100%;" src="img/view.jpg" alt="">
 </div>
</div>
```

And the js File-

```
function showCarousel(){
  if ( $( "#img_slider" ).is( ":hidden" ) ) {
    $( "#img_slider" ).slideDown( "slow" );
  } else {
    $("#img_slider").slideUp("slow");
  }
}
```

Right now, when I click on any image the first #img_slider is open. which is make cense.
Also, having 2 same ID's is not good.
If anyone has an idea of how to implement the wanted functionality that will be great. 
Tanx!

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like the following:

```js
function init () {
  $(".item").each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $imgSlider = $this.find(".img_slider");
    $this.find(".click").click(function () {
      showCarousel($imgSlider);
    });
  });
};

function showCarousel($imgSlider){
  if ($imgSlider.is(":hidden")) {
    $imgSlider.slideDown("slow");
  } else {
    $imgSlider.slideUp("slow");
  }
};

init();
```

```html
<div class="page-wrap">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="img_slider" class="col-md-12">
          <div class="col-md-3"></div>
          <div class="col-md-3"></div>
          <div class="col-md-3"></div>
          <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="click">
      <img style="width:100%;" src="img/frida_calo.jpeg" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="img_slider" class="col-md-12">
          <div class="col-md-3"></div>
          <div class="col-md-3"></div>
          <div class="col-md-3"></div>
          <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="click">
      <img style="width:100%;" src="img/view.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This way the showCarousel-calls will be relevant to the div that is clicked. Note that all id's have been replaced by classes.

Comment: Nice. But know when I click on any image both of the .img_slider slideUp..

Comment: Sorry, I missed one closing div =) Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this once :

```js
$('.tobe').on('click', function(){
  $(this).next('div').find('.img_slider').slideToggle();
  
 });
```

```css
.img_slider{
display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page-wrap">
 <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="img_slider" class="col-md-12">
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
 <div class="tobe">
 <img style="" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="">
 </div>

 <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="img_slider" class="col-md-12">
            <div class="col-md-3">ds</div>
            <div class="col-md-3">ds</div>
            <div class="col-md-3">ds</div>
            <div class="col-md-3">ds</div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
 <div  class="tobe">
    <img style="" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="">
 </div>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="img_slider" class="col-md-12">
            <div class="col-md-3">bi</div>
            <div class="col-md-3">bi</div>
            <div class="col-md-3">bi</div>
            <div class="col-md-3">bi</div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tanx! it is shorter =)